# Sort string array by element length

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string, sorting

Having an array of strings how can I update it so its elements are sorted by its length.

I was trying

```
string[] arr = {"aa","ss","a","abc"};
arr = arr.OrderBy(aux => aux.Length);
```

So, I would get `a,aa,ss,abc`, but it says

> cannot implicitly convert type 'system.linq.iorderedenumerable
>   to string[]'

So, I was doing

```
foreach (string s in arr.OrderBy(str => str.Length))
{
    //
}
```

Is there other way to do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since `arr` is an array, you can use the convenient [`Array.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
Array.Sort(arr, (x, y) => x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length));
foreach (string s in arr)
{
    ...
}
```

This is more efficient than `OrderBy` as it will sort the elements of the array in place rather than creating a new collection to enumerate.

Comment: This is the only method I found, to sort array lengthwise without using Linq and also without creating another array (or any other collection).

Answer (score 14):

`OrderBy` returns `IEnumerable`, not an array. Use `ToArray` method to get an array:

```
arr = arr.OrderBy(aux => aux.Length).ToArray();
```

However, it will not sort the source array. Instead of that, it will create a new one with items sorted and replace the reference. If you need in-place sort (e.g. when the array is also referenced elsewhere) use `Array.Sort` method:

```
Array.Sort(x, (x1, x2) => x1.Length.CompareTo(x2.Length));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using Linq as below:

```
var sortedElements = from arrElement in arr.Distinct()
                     orderby arrElement.Length
                     select arrElement;

foreach (string element in sortedElements)
{
     ...
}
```